# How can i return a string based on an integer without "if" or Lists or Dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x

This is an assignment for college.
I cant use if statements nor if nor Dictionary... (Lists, etc)

I have to return the verbose form of remainder of any number by 5.
I mean something like this

```
14%5 = 4 and I have to return string "Four"
15%5 = 0 --> "Zero"
```

I cant use any modules either.

this might be a silly, but I have been thinking on this for about 4 days and so far no solution

Comment: Ternary expressions /s

Comment: no cant use that either

Comment: It may help if you paste the exact text of the assignment. Based on the bits and pieces that you included, the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Just to clarify, `list` is also no allowed?

Comment: @JonSG yeah no list no dictionary nothing. idk why, but we have to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a crappy assignment that is asking to solve the problem in the wrong way. It is also not 100% clear what is and is not "allowed".

In any case, here are six crappy ways to solve this problem.  Feel free to reject any that are too "list dependent" as it is was not 100% clear if using them is allowed.

```
test_value = 14%5

##----------------
## Use the value as an index into a list
##----------------
print(["zero","one","two","three","four"][test_value])
##----------------

##----------------
## Use the value as an index into a string
##----------------
print("zero one  two  threefour "[test_value*5: test_value*5+5].strip())
##----------------

##----------------
## Use the value to select the correct variable
##----------------
v0 = "zero"
v1 = "one"
v2 = "two"
v3 = "three"
v4 = "four"
print(eval(f"v{test_value}"))
##----------------

##----------------
## Use the value to do replacements
##----------------
print(
    str(test_value)
        .replace("0", "zero")
        .replace("1", "one")
        .replace("2", "two")
        .replace("3", "three")
        .replace("4", "four"))
##----------------

##----------------
## Use the value and some logic and string manipulation
##----------------
print(
    str((test_value == 0 and "zero") or "") +
    str((test_value == 1 and "one") or "") +
    str((test_value == 2 and "two") or "") +
    str((test_value == 3 and "three") or "") +
    str((test_value == 4 and "four") or "")
)
##----------------

##----------------
## simpler version of above
##----------------
print(
    (test_value == 0 and "zero") or
    (test_value == 1 and "one") or
    (test_value == 2 and "two") or
    (test_value == 3 and "three") or
    (test_value == 4 and "four")
)
##----------------
```

Each will give you:

```
four
```